# Cannot start/stop Websphere from the First Steps Window

Tags: websphere

When attempting to start or stop a Websphere 7 service from the First Steps window it fails with the following error;

```
Cannot run program "C:\WebSphere\AppServer\bin\WASService.exe": CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
```

What is causing this and how do you work around the problem?
The command is run by a user who has administrator rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post whole log. Are you able to start/stop service manually from windows services or by running startServer.bat server_name command for /bin directory? When service is created properly, you should get info that windows service is gonna be started as well. Does windows os log (Event Viewer) say anything? Dr. Watsons logs? Doeas this probrem appears only when u start it from First Steps? And finally, were you trying to recreate windows service using WASService.exe?
Regards

Comment: Just from the Windows services.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running this on Windows 7 or Vista. You would need to use "**Run as Administrator**" for startup. The error message gives this away (your account does not have the correct permissions).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a newer Windows OS (2008 and up, I believe), where you have to use the "Run as Administrator" command, in order to execute priviledged commands, such as adding a windows service?

The whole "Administrator user does not really equal full Administrator rights" "feature" in recent windows versions has tripped me up many times.

If so, make sure that, when you open the command line window to execute the WASService.exe command, that you are running cmd.exe "with administrator rights".